# Use Redux and component state is a good idea?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am in the path of implementing redux in some applications and I have a question about the best approach.

In most parts of my application redux fulfills my needs (ssot basically), but for little actions I think it's a lot of bootstrapping (even with redux toolkit), let's say loading screens and such.

So my main question is: is it okay to use component state and redux state both in an application? Does this approach of using both states has implications on performance?

Let's say my redux state has async functions and I'm dispatching from component like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getUserState());    
}, []);
```

But I need a loading state, which I'm handling like this:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getUserState())
     .then(() => { setIsLoading(false) }).catch(error => { console.log(error) });
}, []);
```

Then instead of modifying my reducer to get an isLoading prop, i'm handling it directly in the component. (This is not a direct example of my code but a representation).

What do you think is the best approach for loading states, hide/show child components and such?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conflict nor performance issue when you mix redux and component level state. Rule of thumb, use component level state by default, if that particular state needed to be accessed by any other part of the apps, or forsee to be persisted, or to fulfill architectural needs, place them onto Redux.